# hand Orientation on SynGrasp toolbox for matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using [SynGrasp matlab toolbox](http://sirslab.dii.unisi.it/syngrasp/?page_id=119) to design a hand.
I need to set orientation of hand. It is possible in GUI but  i don't know how to do that in coding.

```
hand = SGparadigmatic;
figure(1)
SGplotHand(hand);
grid on ;
axis('equal');
```

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: yes, but I have not yet received a response